# On image click, link to another activity, displaying that image in full size

Tags: android

I have created a `ListView` and on click on my first view I'm displaying a `GridView` of images. Now i want that when i click on any of that image it gets displayed on another page.

Can you nudge me towards the right direction?

This my code:

1:> Invoking Activity

```
public class ImageExercise extends Activity{
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static int pos;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
                                     {
                                     Intent intent = new Intent(ImageExercise.this,FullImage.class);
                                     pos=position;



                                     startActivity(intent);
                                   // finish();
                                     }

        });

    }
private void showImage(View view, int position) {
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) view; 
    imgView.setImageResource(position); 
    imgView.setId(position);
}


}
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public static Integer[] mThumbIds = {

  R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2,
    R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4,
    R.drawable.sample_5, R.drawable.sample_6,
    R.drawable.sample_7, R.drawable.sample_8,
    R.drawable.sample_9,R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2,
    R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4,
    R.drawable.sample_5, R.drawable.sample_6,
    R.drawable.sample_7, R.drawable.sample_8,
    R.drawable.sample_9


};
    private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

2:-> Invoked Activity to which link is to be made:

```
public class FullImage extends Activity{
     @Override


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        setContentView(R.layout.fullimage);

 }
```

}

Comment: Please share your `ImageAdapter` class. Need to know the source of your images, then we can decide what to do further

Answer (score 1):

First of all, return the drawable resId in the `getItem()` method of the adapter so that it can be accessed from the adapter in the onItemClick callback

```
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public int getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }
}
```

After that in onItemClick callback put the clicked item's resource id in the intent extra

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        int imgResId = (int) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ImageExercise.this,FullImage.class);
        intent.putExtra("ImgResId", imgResId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Finally, In the fullscreen activity get the resource id from the intent extra and set it in the imageView

```
public class FullImage extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ImageView iv = ...
        int imgResId = getIntent().getIntExtra("ImgResId", -1);
        if(imgResId != -1) iv.setImageResource(imgResId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the imagesourceid as intent extra somewhat like this.

```
Intent newintent = new Intent(test.this, image.class);
newintent.putExtra("IMAGE", R.drawable.ico_settings);
```

and then accpet in the destination activity and use as belw

```
int imgid = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE", 0);
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setImageResource(imgid);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the ImageExercise activity in grid item click :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ImageExercise.this,FullImage.class);
 pos=position;
 intent.putExtra("IMAGE", R.drawable.ico_settings);
 startActivity(intent);
```

In your Full Image Activity :

```
int imgid = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE", 0);
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[imgId] );
```